# Is there a n-dimensional alpha-shape algorithm implemented? Or n-dimensional concave hull algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

GGAL(https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/index.html)  is in 2D and 3D. Is there such an algorithm for n-dimensional alpha shapes? And is it implemented? 
Concave hull is related to alpha shapes.

Comment: If I am right, there is a concave hull algorithm in PCL.

Answer (score 2):

The Gudhi library provide a dD alpha-complex. See [here](https://gudhi.inria.fr/doc/latest/group__alpha__complex.html).